# Load DLL from storage on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I currently have 3 projects that are all uploaded to Azure in the same role. Each of these projects contains AjaxControlToolkit.dll which is 6MB.

Hence every upload I do, means 18Mb is instantly taken up with uploading this dll, which I haven't changed in about 1 year.

Is there anyway for DLL's to be retreived from a storage location and added into the project at Azure's end? Or open to any other suggestions to reduce the upload of these DLL's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you indeed can download the .dll from storage - in Visual Studio Solution Explorer tree set "copy local" to "False" to exclude the .dll from the service package. Then in a startup task or inside OnStart() download the file and put it into `bin`.

Comment: Does the OnStart() only occur when the Role is activated and before the application is loaded? I don't want a few seconds of Assembly not found while this is copying.

Comment: As I understand it, there's no 100% guarantee that this will happen. So it may be prudent to handle the errors for a few seconds/minutes.

Comment: OnStart() is invoked for every role instance during startup. HTTP requests will not normally be queued to a web role instance until its `OnStart()` returns `true`. Also downloading several megabytes from within the same datacenter takes couple of seconds.